# How to Add "Add" button in the Bootstrap Datetime picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add button "Add" in the inline Bootstrap Datetime picker. If we click Add button the value should display in input field closing the calndar.From
[Here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline) I was trying to implement to add button.Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written so far?

Comment: Hey I am working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/36ypydn1/9/). sorry for not providing code

Comment: Not sure what u want but check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814985/how-to-add-add-button-in-the-bootstrap-datetime-picker/45818250#45818250

Answer (score 1):

Their is one way to do so.

Don't know which input field you were talking about because date-time is already displayed in one input field but for sake i have added a button inline to display the same data in other input field and this button also closes the popup calendar.

Below code just displays the date-time value without formatting it in other input field.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  let elem = $('#datetimepicker1 input[type=text]');
  let display = $('#date');
  let popup = $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget'); // calendar popup class
  let value = $(elem).val();

  $(popup).remove();
  $(display).val(value).focus();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class='input-group-addon'>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-addon add">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus add"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style='margin-top: 20px;'>
          <input class='form-control' type='text' id='date'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope, you might get some idea from this code. :)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help. Is it possible to add "+" add button inside the calendar so that i can click add button after selecting date and time @Chaitanya

Comment: Not sure but for custom add button check this out http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-icons

Comment: that function is for adding icons